# CmdExec Powershell Job Step Escape Double Quotes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, jobs, powershell

I have a PowerShell job step I'm trying to execute and it's failing with a syntax error I believe is because I'm trying to escape double-quotes in my code. Can anyone take a look and help me with getting the escape characters right, or tweaking my code.

```
powershell.exe "Compress-Archive -Path \\NAS\DB-backups\BackupFiles -DestinationPath `"\\NAS\DB-Backups\BackupFiles $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).zip`" -CompressionLevel Optimal"
```

I've also tried it using \ as the escape character

```
powershell.exe "Compress-Archive -Path \\NAS\DB-backups\BackupFiles -DestinationPath \"\\NAS\DB-Backups\BackupFiles $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).zip\" -CompressionLevel Optimal"
```

I tried running this script (with \ escape characters) in the command line and it ran fine. Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you're having has to do with [SQL Server Agent Tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps?view=sql-server-2017) as referred to by this Stack Exchange post [SQL Agent - PowerShell step “syntax error”](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58669/sql-agent-powershell-step-syntax-error/58679#58679)

Excerpting from that post

> This is a not very intuitive and I was never able to find anything
>   concrete on the explanation [e.g. no exact BOL or white paper was
>   found]. The syntax error in the SQL Agent job is a T-SQL syntax error
>   based on User Tokens. So that basically means that a PowerShell
>   Sub-Expression Operator is treated as a Token to SQL Server Agent. So
>   in PowerShell this $( ) appears to be treated as reserved character
>   sequence for SQL Server Agent.

Referencing your attempts,

```
$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).zip
```

notice the $( where you're trying to get the current date for the zip file.  That syntax is a Powershell sub-expression. This part is attempting to be interpreted by the SQL Server Agent as a token.

My suggestion would be to separate out the sub-expression into another Powershell variable ($ZipDate) first and then use that to finish the Powershell command.

Try this:

```
powershell.exe "$ZipDate = (get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd); Compress-Archive -Path "C:\TestCompress" -DestinationPath "c:\TestCompressOut\$ZipDate.zip" -CompressionLevel Optimal"
```