# SQL/Powershell job failing

Tags: sql-server-2016, powershell

Need more help from you brilliant folks.

I am trying to import a CSV file to a SQL table with this code:

```
$SQLServer = "MYSQLINSTANCE"
$SQLDatabase = "DBATools"
$SQLString = "Server=$SQLServer;Database=$SQLDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
$SQLTable = "dbo.MyTable"
$CSVFile = "\\remotesrvr\OutputShare\Output.csv"
$Header = 'RecordedDTM','TablespaceName','PhysicalFileName','MaxSize','UsedSize','FreeSize','PctUsed'
Import-CSV -Path $CSVFile -Header $Header | Select-Object -Skip 1 | ForEach-Object {Invoke-SqlCmd -ConnectionString $SQLString -Query "INSERT INTO $SQLTable VALUES ('SVPPDRMDB01','$($_.RecordedDTM)','$($_.TablespaceName)','$($_.PhysicalFileName)',$($_.MaxSize),$($_.UsedSize),$($_.FreeSize),$($_.PctUsed))"}
```

It runs successfully in a Powershell prompt, but when I create a SQL job of type Powershell, I get the following error:

```
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: line(7): Syntax error).  The step failed
```

Not a lot of help, huh. What am i missing?

Comment: See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217256/60085) answer about SQL Agent tokens.  Specifically, related to your use of `$($_.RecordedDTM)` syntax.

Comment: I generally recommend against using the PowerShell job step type. Instead use a CmdExec step to call PowerShell to call your script. That extra layer turns out to resolve a lot of confusion around PowerShell job steps being special

Comment: Well, that just stinks. But maybe Microsoft has good reasons for it to work the way it does. I did end up running the script outside SQL Server just like the comment above stated.