# PowerShell Script Not Working on SQL Server Job Step

Tags: sql-server, jobs, powershell

I've some .CSV files generated in a shared folder `\\SERVER01\DIR\Current` and would like to copy to another folder in same server `\\SERVER01\DIR\Archive`.

The script needs to copy, rename files adding timestamp, and then remove from the source folder. PS script works very well on PowerShell ISE or Windows PowerShell, but, when I try to schedule same script in a SQL Server Job, I'm receiving errors below:

```
$source = "\\SERVER01\DIR\Current" $destination = "\\SERVER01\DIR\Archive"

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Include *.csv | % {
    $name = $_.Name.Split(".")[0] + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".csv"
    #$name = "Finished_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".csv"
    #$name = "Finished_" + $_.Name.Split(".")[0] +  "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".csv"
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName $name
    Move-Item "$($_.Directory)\$name" -Destination $destination }
```

I've received error below:

```
Message
Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: line(9): Syntax error).  The step failed.
```

After receiving the error above, I've changed Line(9) as below:

```
$source = "\\SERVER01\DIR\Current"
$destination = "\\SERVER01\DIR\Archive"

Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Include *.csv | % {
    $name = $_.Name.Split(".")[0] + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".csv"
    #$name = "Finished_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".csv"
    #$name = "Finished_" + $_.Name.Split(".")[0] +  "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date -Format yyyymmdd) + "_" + ($_.CreationTime | Get-Date  -Format hhmmss) + ".csv"
    Rename-Item $_ -NewName $name
    Move-Item "\\SERVER01\DIR\Current\$name" -Destination $destination
}
```

Then, received another error:

```
Message
The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:  
A job step received an error at line 4 in a PowerShell script. 
The corresponding line is 'Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Include *.csv | % {  '. 
Correct the script and reschedule the job. 
The error information returned by PowerShell is: 
'Cannot find path '\\SERVER01\DIR\Current' because it does not exist.  '.  
Process Exit Code 0.  The step succeeded.
```

After that, I've tried to change line(9) again, using `$source` parameter:

```
Move-Item $source + "\" + $name -Destination $destination
```

But, it didn't work and return same error above: *'Cannot find path '\SERVER01\DIR\Current' because it does not exist.'.*

It looks like `$($_.Directory)...` is not working in a SQL Server job. Not sure why and how to solve it?

I'm using SQL Server Agent to schedule it to be executed after some others steps which are being executed on SQL Server in the same job.

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/217256/60085) that discusses the issues with SQL Agent job token syntax and how that might contribute to your problem, since it seems to work fine under native Powershell

Comment: Maybe PowerShell can call the job (or do whatever the job does) and then do its thing. SQL Server shouldn't be moving stuff around in your filesystem, IMHO.

Comment: @AaronBertrand in this case, schedule PS script to be executed on daily basis only through Task Scheduler?

Comment: Sure, my order of preference for scheduling OS-based things: 1. Task Scheduler 2. `Start-Job` / `PSScheduledJob` ... 99. SQL Server Agent

Comment: I've used SQL command step to launch powershell scripts with great success.  I definitely don't try and run the native SQLPS that's baked in, it's too hard to work with.  By which I mean something like powershell.exe -script "path to script file"

Comment: HI Guys, I've done through Powershell, using Task Scheduler as suggested by @AaronBertrand ! Thanks for all your advices and inputs! :)